# Use multiple config files for HornetQ server

Tags: jms, configuration-files, hornetq

I'm using hornetq(2.2.14) standalone server(s). I should define about 1000 (jms)queues and so many diverts and core bridges between them!

1. Can i define (jms)queues in separate files (multiple hornetq-jms.xml files)?
2. What can i do for diverts and core bridges? (Can i define them in separate files?)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to split your xml files, and include the shared configuration in different hornetq instances. There is already a question that does explains how to do that: [Can we import XML file into another XML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121052/can-we-import-xml-file-into-another-xml-file)