# importing xml file and SlowCheetah

Tags: c#, .net, xml, app-config, slowcheetah

I want to import an xml file inside of an element in my app.config file but the only method which works for that task causes SlowCheetah to fail with the following error:

> The "SlowCheetah.Tasks.TransformXml" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The URI is empty.

The import method I tried was to declare a parsed external entity and then use it in my element declaration as explained in the top answer to this question: [Can we import XML file into another XML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121052/can-we-import-xml-file-into-another-xml-file)

Comment: Can you show us the part of your transformation file that fails?

Comment: I think SlowCheetah itself is failing because I'm not transforming the element that's imported. Literally the only information I get about the error is what's posted already.

Comment: Well, without seeing the part where your import is done it's hard to help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XDT (the tech that drives web.config transforms) does not support XML entities. If you'd like this support the best thing to do is add an entry at http://aspnet.uservoice.com/.