# How to seperate servlet web.xml file into 2 or more XML files

Tags: java, servlets, web, config, web.xml

If my web application have too many servlet class and filter, I think put all in the same document is too complex, I want to konw how could I seperate it to 2 or more XML file.

Comment: Perhaps you should prefer to use [annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaeo.html).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

XML allows external entities (other XML files) to be imported. Relevant question here - [Can we import XML file into another XML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121052/can-we-import-xml-file-into-another-xml-file).

Comment: As to web.xml, this works only in older Tomcat versions and is a security bug. It was fixed in newer Tomcat versions. Regardless, if you found a duplicate question, flag/vote as duplicate, do not post it as a link-only answer for the sake of reputation.