# Reusable XML node

Tags: xml

I want to create a XML file in which I want to use a node with subnodes inside in other nodes(REUSABLE).

If I am using this node again and again, my XML will be too long. 
Is there any way to write node only once and refer (or link) it whereever necessary?

Comment: Actually I want to use a node which contains a subnode (information) and that node I want to refer whereever necessary (as a reference)
I am also thinking wether can I use XSD?

Answer (score 0):

I may have a suggestion, but it will depend on how you use the xml file and who who takes care of it.

You could make a `special`(*special to you*) tag that will mean something for you when you parse the xml.

For example:

```
<notes>
    <note>
        <to>Person1</to>
        <myAddress></myAddress>
        <heading>Reminder</heading>
        <body>Don't forget to do stuff</body>
    </note>
    <note>
        <to>Person2</to>
        <myAddress></myAddress>
        <heading>Assignment</heading>
        <body>You need to do stuff!</body>
    </note>
    ....
</notes>

<myAddressDef>
    <name>Me</name>
    <position>Boss</position>  <!-- Because why not :) -->
    ....
</myAddressDef>
```

Every time you encounter `myAddress` tag, you will know that it's „defined” under the `myAddressDef` tag and get the content from there.

Comment: Thanks
If I need the following same node in different nodes(multiple time), can I use ref="something" ?
<note>
        <to>Person1</to>
        <myAddress></myAddress>
        <heading>Reminder</heading>
        <body>Don't forget to do stuff</body>
    </note>
If multiple times I am using the same node, it will be duplication
So how to refer a node it is still a problem

Comment: @Amol I don't quite understand what you mean. Being the one who parses the xml, you can do pretty much anything you want. Maybe if you post an example of what you are trying to achieve, thing will get more clear.

Comment: @Amol , Do you want to reuse the book tag with another values? If so, the thing to do is use them as they are; else, the whole meaning of xml is lost and a simple csv file would do the trick for less space.

Comment: yes, exactly same, place a common tag or node which is same and present  in other nodes and whenever required, just refer it.

Comment: Well, for that, I really like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5127928/4153931). It's easy to use and it doesn't require as much work as my approach.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Is there any example for including the NODE?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91372/discussion-between-cristian-marian-and-amol).

Comment: Can you please tell me its link again?

Comment: It's the accepted answer from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121052/can-we-import-xml-file-into-another-xml-file