# ITRS Geneos monitoring tool ( how to include one sampler within another sampler)

Tags: geneos

I have 4 different database environments, so I have to write 4 different sampler for each environment and each sampler has sql queries as well as database connection.

e.g. database_test1_sampler

```
1) sql queries ( same for all environment)
2) database connection (different for each environment)
```

SQL queries are same for all environment but database connection is different for each environment.

My requirement is that, i need to extract sql queries in one sampler and include that sampler in another sampler.

e.g. database_query_sampler

```
1) sql queries
```

database_test1_sampler

```
1) include database_query_sampler here
2) database connection (different for each environment)
```

final result will be

e.g. database_test1_sampler

```
1) sql queries
2) database connection
```

So that it will help me to add/update/delete sql query in only one sampler database_query_sampler.

In xml, we can include one xml into another by using ENTITY tag
e.g.
[Can we import XML file into another XML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121052/can-we-import-xml-file-into-another-xml-file)

In there any way, same functionality can be achieved in geneos sampler.

Answer (score 1):

1. Define an environment variable each for each database like database username, password, schema.
2. Use variables wherever possible in your sampler.
3. When attaching the sampler/type to managed entity, there is an option in managed entity to refer to an environment variable.

Wooha! You are done! You will have only one generic sampler for each database and an ennvironment variable each for each database.