# Import XML into XSL that does not have namespace on root node

Tags: xml, firefox, xslt, namespaces

I am trying to use XSL to transform two XML files into HTML.  I have everything working, but I have a problem.  One of the XML files contains assorted bits of information that I am pulling from.  There are no namespace declarations anywhere in the file, but nodes that I need to access are namespace prefixed.  My original fix was to add the namespaces to the root node, but I found out I can't do that as the files can't be modified.

If I leave the namespaces off, I get the following in Firefox:

```
XML Parsing Error: prefix not bound to a namespace
```

The namespaces should be (but don't exist in the source XML):

```
xmlns:prop="http://www.blank.com/prop" 
xmlns:item="http://www.blank.com/item"
```

How do I solve this?

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<collection>
  <prop:id>123</prop:id>
  <document>
    <item:name>Document</item:name>
  </document>
</collection>
```

XSL:
(neither of the value-of elements work)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:variable name="propsPath" select="test_Props.xml"/>
  <xsl:variable name="props" select="document($propsPath)" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html><body><div>
      <xsl:value-of select="$props/collection/*[local-name() = 'id']"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="$props/collection/prop:id"/>
    </div></body></html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If your input uses prefixes without binding them to a namespace, then it's not a well-formed XML document and cannot be processed by XSLT.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** This post does not solve the specific question. Nevertheless I leave it here, because it exemplifies a solution to the general problem.

One solution I found to circumvent the namespace issue without modifying `test_Props.xml` is using an *entity reference* in a stub file.

So your `test_Props.xml` file is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<collection>
  <prop:id>123</prop:id>
  <document>
    <item:name>Document</item:name>
  </document>
</collection>
```

Now create a stub file around this content named `test_Props_stub.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE doc [
<!ENTITY otherFile SYSTEM "test_Props.xml">
]>
<root xmlns:prop="http://www.blank.com/prop" xmlns:item="http://www.blank.com/item">
&otherFile;
</root>
```

This solution is inspired by [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5127928/1305969).
Then just modify the `document`'s name and its path in your XSLT by adding the new root node and you're done:

```
<xsl:variable name="propsPath" select="'test_Props_stub.xml'"/>
<xsl:variable name="props" select="document($propsPath)/root" />
```

The rest can stay unmodifyed.
Now the namespaces from the `root` node of the stub file are applied to the original XML file and the XPath expressions *do match*.

---

BTW you had a minor but nasty bug in the following line:

```
<xsl:variable name="propsPath" select="test_Props.xml"/>
```

You forgot the quotes around the filename.

Comment: <!ENTITY otherFile SYSTEM "test_Props.xml"> does not work with Firefox unfortunately.  I should have stated that I tried that.  I apologize.