# Does including xml into another xml still work in modern browsers?

Tags: xml

I was trying the examples from [Can we import XML file into another XML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121052/can-we-import-xml-file-into-another-xml-file) with entities and with xinclude option.
I have my own http server serving xml files and tried opening them using https://localhost/file.xml.

I tried exactly the same examples as mentioned in that post for Xinclude and XML external entities. The examples from the page mentioned do not work for me. I see that fetching the first xml file finishes with http 200 and I do not see in http server logs the request for fetching the second file. I also requested my colleague to try it and also it does not work for him.

I tried it on the latest Firefox and Chrome.

Has anyone tried this in modern web browsers?

Comment: It sound like the connection is not completing.  Are you getting a response with a status like 200 OK, or 400/500 error?  XML does work if the server is programmed to return an xml response.  Not all servers support XML responses.

Comment: There are multiple different approaches in answers to that question. Please provide a [mcve] of your attempt (and be more specific than "modern browsers", which browsers have you actually tried this in?).

Comment: Updated with the comment mentioned